# How to include null value in the JSON via NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, null, nsjsonserialization

I think I get it how to use the NSJSONSerialization over all. The call I am making is:

```
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:&error]
```

where *parameters* is a NSDictionary which includes keys and values to use in the JSON request. Everything is fine and all, until I have to use **null** as a value instead of an empty string. I can't find a way to set the value as **null** at all. The example of *json* that I need to create is:

```
{"target"
  {"firstname":<firstname>,
   "lastname":<lastname>},
 "error":null
}
```

The way server is setup is that it's expecting either an error as a string or a *null* if there's no error.

Any ideas? Am I missing an API call or something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You have to use `NSNull`. For instance

**Swift**

```
let dict = ["firstKeyHasValue": 2342, "secondKeyHasNoValue": NSNull()]
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"error": [NSNull null] };
```

From the official documentation of [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Neither a key nor a value can be nil; if you need to represent a null value in a dictionary, you should use NSNull.

Answer (score 6):

I tried doing this and worked for me.

```
var param: [String:Any] = [:]

param["firstName"] = "somename"

param["middleName"] = NSNull()

param["lastName"] = "somename"

print(param)
```

**Result:**

```
["firstName":"somename","middleName":null,"lastName":"somename"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swifty JSON, I've just created [a PR](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/pull/610) that should handle nil. It's not merged yet and might need some improvements.
The [part](https://github.com/gsabran/SwiftyJSON/blob/swift3/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L519-L589) that describes how to do that should be a good start to write your own implementation if you need to. The logic is not that complicated but there might be tricky edge cases/performance things to think about.

I know it's not a direct response to the question since it's replacing `NSJSONSerialization`, but I hope it can help some people frustrated by how Swift handles nil/json!

Answer (score -4):

Just try something like this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonObj = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"My Name", @"name", @"Developer", @"occupation", NULL, @"My NULL field", nil];
```

and use this object as parameter where you want it.

Comment: [NSNull null], not NULL.

Comment: you can't insert nil values in a NSDictionary